# Saving Agnes Object in R

Tags: r, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis

Apologies if this is really basic - is there a way to save an Agnes object from the Cluster library in R to a file for use in another session?  I've looked at the CRAN pdf and for a similar question here on Stackoverflow but don't see anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think `saveRDS` will work with any R object (at least for every object that resides in memory. Special objects that are distributed over mutliple machines probably won't work)

Comment: Thanks!  I though saveRDS only worked for dataframes but now I know better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

```
library(cluster)

data(animals)
aa.ga <- agnes(animals, method = "gaverage")

saveRDS(aa.ga,"aa.ga.RDS") # Save it

rm(aa.ga) # Remove it so I can prove this works

aa.ga <- readRDS("aa.ga.RDS") # Read it back in

aa.ga
```

> ```
> Call:  agnes(x = animals, method = "gaverage")  Agglomerative coefficient:  0.8285911  Order of objects:
> ```
>
> [1] ant lob fly her liz sal bee cpl spi cat chi man cow lio rab duc eag ele wha fro Height
>   (summary):    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
>        0.0000  0.0000  1.2050  0.9573  1.5890  2.6230
>
> ```
> Available components: [1] "order"     "height"    "ac"        "merge"  "diss"      "call"      "method"    "order.lab" "data"
> ```

Comment: Thanks!  Thought saveRDS only worked for dataframes but now I know better!